# excel using VBA entering days in calendar

Tags: vba, excel, calendar

What I am trying to do;
I want a calendar I can put appointments in then when the appointment is done add the amount charged to my appointment as income, also be able to add when I buy supplies to the day I buy them and how much and have it as expenses. Then have that information (income/expenses) populate in another tab that can be printed out and taken to accountant for doing taxes.

I am working on the calendar part but having issues with the days appearing in the correct columns. I have 3 columns for each box for the days, so that I will be able to add data later.  I can get the days to populate in the calendar but I need them to skip two columns each time but they are not.

I am including the code and a snip of how it is coming out at this time.

```
Sub CreateCalendar()
Dim csheet As Worksheet
Set csheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

selDate = [b1]
fMon = DateSerial(Year(selDate), Month(selDate), 1)
lMon = CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(fMon, 0))

stRow = 4

'clear last cal
Rows(4).ClearContents
Rows(10).ClearContents
Rows(16).ClearContents
Rows(22).ClearContents
Rows(28).ClearContents
Rows(34).ClearContents


'determine what weekday 1st is. . .
If Weekday(fMon) = 1 Then
    stCol = 4
ElseIf Weekday(fMon) = 4 Then
    stCol = 7
ElseIf Weekday(fMon) = 7 Then
    stCol = 10
ElseIf Weekday(fMon) = 10 Then
    stCol = 13
ElseIf Weekday(fMon) = 13 Then
    stCol = 16
ElseIf Weekday(fMon) = 16 Then
    stCol = 19
ElseIf Weekday(fMon) = 19 Then
    stCol = 22
End If

For x = 1 To Day(lMon)
If FirstT = Empty Then
    csheet.Cells(stRow, stCol) = fMon
    FirstT = 1
Else
    fMon = fMon + 1
    csheet.Cells(stRow, stCol) = fMon
End If

If stCol = 22 Then
    stCol = 4
    stRow = stRow + 8
Else
    stCol = stCol + 1
End If

Next x

End Sub
```

[Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM8H7.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "I need them to skip two columns each time"?

Comment: If I run your code (actually needed to change to get just the Day), using a date of 3/1/2017, then it puts 1 thru 16 in row 4 (col G-V), then 17 - 31 in row 12 (col D-R).  Do you really want it to be more than 7 days wide?

Comment: Sorry had wrong image posted.  it will only be 7 days but i need day 2 where day 4 is and day 3 were day 7 is and so forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code and I believe it works as you want. 
Note: (1) I hard-coded a date for testing; you need to change it back
(2) Your code to 'ClearContents' every 6 lines differs from your code to increment by 8 lines. I set to 6 lines. (3) you can remove where I placed day names in first row.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateCalendar()
Dim csheet As Worksheet
Dim selDate As Date
Dim fMon    As Long
Dim lMon    As Long
Dim stRow   As Integer
Dim stCol   As Integer
Dim FirstT  As Integer
Dim x       As Integer
Dim iColOffset  As Integer



    Set csheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    selDate = #1/1/2017#     '[b1]
    fMon = DateSerial(Year(selDate), Month(selDate), 1)
    lMon = CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(fMon, 0))

    iColOffset = 4      ' Set default starting column
    'I added the following code so I could keep track... you can delete
    Cells(1, iColOffset) = "Sunday"
    Cells(1, iColOffset + 3) = "Monday"
    Cells(1, iColOffset + 6) = "Tuesday"
    Cells(1, iColOffset + 9) = "Wednesday"
    Cells(1, iColOffset + 12) = "Thursday"
    Cells(1, iColOffset + 15) = "Friday"
    Cells(1, iColOffset + 18) = "Saturday"

    stRow = 4           ' Starting Row

    'clear last cal
    Rows(4).ClearContents
    Rows(10).ClearContents
    Rows(16).ClearContents
    Rows(22).ClearContents
    Rows(28).ClearContents
    Rows(34).ClearContents


    'determine what weekday 1st is. . .
    Debug.Print "First DOW = " & Weekday(fMon)
    stCol = Weekday(fMon)       ' Set starting column
'    If Weekday(fMon) = 1 Then
'        stCol = 1
'    ElseIf Weekday(fMon) = 2 Then
'        stCol = 2
'    ElseIf Weekday(fMon) = 3 Then
'        stCol = 3
'    ElseIf Weekday(fMon) = 10 Then
'        stCol = 4
'    ElseIf Weekday(fMon) = 13 Then
'        stCol = 5
'    ElseIf Weekday(fMon) = 16 Then
'        stCol = 6
'    ElseIf Weekday(fMon) = 19 Then
'        stCol = 7
'    End If

    For x = 1 To Day(lMon)
        If FirstT = Empty Then
            csheet.Cells(stRow, iColOffset + (stCol * 3) - 3) = Day(CDate(fMon))
            FirstT = 1
        Else
            fMon = fMon + 1
            csheet.Cells(stRow, iColOffset + (stCol * 3) - 3) = Day(CDate(fMon))
        End If

        'Debug.Print iColOffset + (stCol * 3) - 3
        If iColOffset + (stCol * 3) - 3 = 22 Then
            stCol = 1
            ' *** NOTE!! Your code doesn't match.
            ' Above, you clear every 6 Rows (4, 10, 16, 22...), but here you are incrementing by 8.
            ' Which is it?
            'stRow = stRow + 8
            stRow = stRow + 6               ' I changed to 6 to match what you clear
        Else
            stCol = stCol + 1
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked now on the the next part .